# Actually i'm trying to test a function from Nestjs and getting that error:

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have compilation level error

```js
import { CompletedSurveyRepositoryService } from 'src/database/completed-survey/completed-survey.repository.service';
                                                  ^
```

Comment: More information on what you are doing and what is happening would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use relative path, like this

```js
import { CompletedSurveyRepositoryService } from '../../database/completed-survey/completed-survey.repository.service';
```

Comment: But i don't want relative path import, because lot of code change, their is any way to get rid of that(relative path)